# ElementNotVisibleError when using headless chrome for testing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, testing, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I test following assumption `And I click on the text "2018/2019" within ".year"` with capybara/headless_chrome and constantly get the error

```
element not visible
    (Session info: headless chrome=67.0.3396.87)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.5 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
```

I've already tried to adjust the window size, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701561/chrome-headless-element-not-visible/50506257). But it didn't work.
My step definition:

```
When(/^(?:|I )click on the text "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/) do |link, selector|
  begin
    page.find(:css, selector).click
  end
end
```

The element is actually visible and found by Capybara

[image]

```
[1] pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> page.find(:css, ".year")
    => #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="a" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li/a">
```

But click fails

```
[2] pry(#<Cucumber::Rails::World>)> page.find(:css, ".year").click
    Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
```

Why doesn't `click` work here?

EDIT:
The HAML of the link is

```
           %ul.facet_values
            - unselected.each do |facet_value|
              %li.filtered{data: {hayf: {text: facet_value.name.downcase}}}
                = link_to facet_value.path, title: facet_value.name, class: 'year' do
                  =truncate("#{facet_value.name}", length: 24)
                - if facet.has_counts?
                  %span.small="(#{facet_value.count})"
```

I tried headless testing with `Poltergeist` and got `Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html body header div.container-fluid' at this position` which was solved with `.trigger('click')` and the test passed.

Comment: Because Selenium was designed to only interact with the page as a user would. Since users can't interact with invisible elements, Selenium won't allow it. My guess is that you've mistakenly got the wrong element and the element you've got is not visible. Check your locator in the dev console using `$$(.year)`. How many elements does it return? If it's more than one, your locator is not unique. If the element that you want is the first in the collection, you'll be fine but my guess is that it's not. You will likely need to find a more unique way to locate that element.

Comment: The element is visible and i checked it in the console. 
`$$('.year')` returns `[a.year]` which is an array with length 1. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's great... so now it's likely a timing issue. Have you tried adding a wait? You can wait for the element to be clickable and then click it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35764578/2386774) and [this](https://gist.github.com/kenrett/7553278) for some examples.

Comment: Does it work in non-headless? You haven’t set `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` have you? What is the actual HTML? –

Comment: @JeffC Assuming the OP hasn't done anything silly (like setting `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false`) it's unlikely to be timing since Capybara has built-in waiting/retrying behavior

Comment: @ThomasWalpole OK. Thanks. I'm familiar with Selenium on C# and Java and was trying to apply some troubleshooting to this situation without specific language experience. I'm kinda at a loss here then since the locator seems good and it shouldn't be a timing issue...

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, that might well be something silly. The test doesn't work in non-headless also, since we have Selenium for them.
I do have `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` in `env.rb`, since I want Capybara to interact with hidden elements

Comment: I tried headless testing with `Poltergeist` and got `Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html body header div.container-fluid' at this position` which was solved with `.trigger('click')` and the test passed.

Comment: @AnnaKizilova Setting `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` when testing an app is a terrible idea (might make some sense if scraping rather than testing) since it ends up making most tests invalid and you can't actually interact with non-visible elements.  If there are a few places where you actually do need to find non-visible elements, then use the `visible: :hidden` option which all Capybara element finding methods accept in those few instances.   Using `trigger('click')` with Poltergeist when testing is the same since it makes your test invalid and pointless.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thank you for explanation. I'm quite a newbie in programming in general and have so many things yet to learn. What would you advise in that case?

Comment: @AnnaKizilova Added as an answer due to comment length limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this doesn't work in non-headless Chrome or Poltergeist, then the simplest answer is that the element isn't actually visible.  Firstly remove the `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` setting since that makes no sense when testing an app, and will screw up all sorts of waiting behaviors. Secondly use `save_and_open_screenshot` to get a picture of what the page actually looks like before you are trying to click the link.

I'm guessing you'll see that the link isn't actually visible at that point and your test is missing a step a user would have to do to make the link visible, is it in a menu where you have to hover over a different element first? is it in a popup where you have to click on something else first?, does it need to be scrolled to? etc.

Finally, you'll generally have less issues if you stick with Chrome via Selenium. Poltergeist uses PhantomJS which hasn't been updated in quite some time and doesn't support modern JS or CSS which can lead to all sorts of strangeness.

Comment: Thank you. 
My general goal is getting rid of PhantomJS and transfer to Selenium, thus i'm fixing the tests to use headless_chrome.
I made the screenshot and the link is there (please see the question). Will follow other suggestions.

Comment: @AnnaKizilova  Is the picture in the question from an actual test run? If so where is the header element Poltergeist complained about? Non of the drivers think it’s visible, so either the picture isn’t showing the element you think, or there’s an overlaying element.  Run in non-headless and inspect the page using the browser console

Comment: you were absolutely right. The element was buried inside a toggled div. I added a couple of steps to make it visible and the test passed. Thank you for being very polite and patient with a newbie. Such attitude encourages asking questions on SO.